# Is calling function_exists() faster or slower that apply_filters()

Tags: filters, function-exists

Is calling function_exists() faster or slower that apply_filters() ... or is the difference so small that it should not be considered?

I did a bit of testing based on Kaiser's and it showed that function_exists() is ~3 times faster where both the function and filter exist. and ~11 times faster if the filter does not exist. Was not expecting this.

```
function taco_party() {
    return true;
}

add_filter( 'taco-party', 'taco_party' );

timer_start();
for ( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++ )  {
    $test = apply_filters( 'taco-party', '' );
}
echo( 'Seconds: ' . timer_stop( 0, 10 ) . '<br />' );

timer_start();
for ( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++ )  {
    if ( function_exists( 'taco_party' ) ) {
        $test = taco_party();
    }
}
echo( 'Seconds: ' . timer_stop( 0, 10 ) . '<br />' );
```

Bear in mind that this is running each method 1,000,000 times which is quite a lot. Each method ran once completes very, very quickly:

```
Test 1: 0.0000491142
Test 2: 0.0000140667
```

I would conclude that the difference is not an issue.

Comment: Aren't they two different things? If you want to know if calling a function directly is faster than calling it trough a wrapper function like `call_user_func`, then obviously yes, but the differences are negligible.

Comment: Totally, but in the context of a theme using a plugin's functionality these 2 different methods are used to accomplish the same task.

Comment: Now, if you put those numbers in the context of an overall query (much less, a pageload), I'm guessing that the difference (30 *micro* seconds) is not statistically significant.

Comment: Situations in which you need to make sure a function exists are pretty rare; most of the times you know it exists and just call it

Comment: Wait: is this even a *real-world* test? Shouldn't you compare *over-riding a function* to *applying a filter*?

Comment: I edited my answer with what I think *might* be a more relevant comparison.

Comment: My test is relevant to my use case ... In all honesty, I should have wrote a clearer question :)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if one is faster or slower than the other, but I would suggest that using `apply_filters()` is the *better* approach, because it is *cleaner*, and more intuitive (in the sense of doing things the "WordPress way").

**EDIT**

If you're doing comparison tests, shouldn't you compare the time required to execute the following:

This:

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists( 'taco_party' ) ) {
    function taco_party( $salsa = true ) {
        return $salsa;
    }
}

function taco_party( $salsa = true ) {
    return $salsa;
}
?>
```

Versus This:

```
<?php
function taco_party( $salsa = true ) {
    return apply_filters( 'taco-party', $salsa );
}
function hot_salsa() {
    $salsa = true;
    return $salsa;
}
add_filter( 'taco-party', 'hot_salsa' );
?>
```

It's not just the time required to check for the *existence* of the function or filter, but rather the time required to *do something*.

Comment: Totally agree Chip! Someone asked if one was more resource intensive than the other and I really didn't have an answer.

Comment: We're actually taking about 2 different applications of function_exists(). Your test is good for "maybe defining a function in functions.php if the function has not been defined in a child theme". My test is for assigning a function to a filter in a plugin and using the filter inside the theme to display data. I believe that my test checks what it needs to. But really, we are talking about 2 different things here :)

Comment: Okay, I gotcha; you're thinking specifically in the context of a Plugin, that requires something to be added to the template, but can't use a standard/core hook to do so: create a template tag (that gets wrapped in a `function_exists()` conditional), or define a custom filter. And in my case, I'm thinking in the context of a Theme that is designed to be over-ridden.

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: The numbers are out of a non-vanilla install, so it could be less on both sides

WordPress has ~ *2.700* functions & ~ *250* attached actions in `global $wp_filter;`

*So the Q could be:*

> Is iterating through the (at this point) existing functions faster than iterating through the array of hooked filters?

Imo filters/hooks are the faster way, more safe and easier to backtrace. My choice would be filters.

Comment: `filters/hooks are the faster way` => and this statement is based on... ? I highly doubt it they are faster, but as I said the difference in speed insignificant

Comment: "Imo" means: "In my opinion", which is a guess based on the amount.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after running several tests<sup>1)</sup> I can see that `has_filter` takes ~ 20% more time to finish (on a not vanilla install) than `function_exists`:

```
// You have to uncomment one or the other to run the test
// don't run timer_xy() functions behind each other - the result is then wrong
timer_start();
$output = ' false ';
for ( $i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++ ) 
{
    // if ( function_exists('wp_login') ) $output = ' true ';
    if ( has_filter( 'shutdown' ) ) $output = ' true ';
}
echo $output;
echo('Seconds: ' . timer_stop(0,10) . '<br />');
```

<sup>1)</sup> This is the code I used to test. It was set on the top of the functions.php file

Comment: Thanks for running the test! The question was comparing apply_filters() to function_exists() not has_filter().

Comment: N/P. Could you please update your Q with the actual code you're using? Hard to imagine your use case at the moment.

Comment: The use case, as far as I understand it, is comparing the use of `apply_filters()` vs. a pluggable function, for Themes designed to allow themselves to be overridden by Child Themes. So, if a Theme adds some content via function, it could wrap that function in a `function_exists()` call, or it could wrap the *content inside the function* in an `apply_filters()` call.

Comment: Chip, That's one use case for sure. Another is a plugin providing filters as an API to access data/functionality.

Comment: Ok. But that's hardly comparable. I took the nearly latest loaded function and the latest hook to compare. How would you setup a test case?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about micro-optimizations here. Stick to apply_filters which is easier to use and allows the end user to also add content before/after your function output if they wanted without copying the entire function over if that's all they want to do. Don't be so concerned about possibly saving 0.000001 seconds on anything. Always focus on clean, easy to read and modular code. PHP keeps getting faster with each update and WordPress sites should be using caching functions anyway to return static code so micro-optimizing is just a waste of time and stress ;)